# how do i resolve this error " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.accountusers' "

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am working on a simple django project with the homepage which displays simple static files stored in my database

I tried to use django-allauth package to get the login with email functionality

I am using docker container so i installed the django-allauth package while the container was running with the following command
"$ docker-compose exec web pipenv install django-allauth==0.52.0"

then i stopped my already running docker container and restarted it again with the --build flag this time to rebuild the whole image again with the following command
" $ docker-compose down
$ docker-compose up -d --build "

then i thought to run migrate to update my database
" docker-compose exec web python manage.py migrate "

i got this error (in the CMD console which was not in administrator mode though but it doesn't matter) after the migration command

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/code/manage.py", line 22, in \<module\>
main()
File "/code/manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
django.setup()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 178, in create
mod = import_module(mod_path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return \_bootstrap.\_gcd_import(name\[level:\], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1204, in \_gcd_import
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1176, in \_find_and_load
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1126, in \_find_and_load_unlocked
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 241, in \_call_with_frames_removed
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1204, in \_gcd_import
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1176, in \_find_and_load
File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1140, in \_find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.accountusers'
```

THIS IS MY setitngs.py FILE

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Third-party
    'crispy_forms', # new
    'allauth',    # new
    'allauth.account'  # new


    # Local
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bookstore_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bookstore_project.wsgi.application'


# Database

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1234!@#$',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}


# Password validation

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),] # new
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') # new
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]

# Default primary key field type

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'  #new
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'  
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home' 

# django-crispy-forms
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4' # new


# django-allauth config
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT = 'home' 

SITE_ID = 1 

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend', 
)

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

AND EVEN MY Pipfile

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
django = "==4.2"
psycopg2-binary = "==2.9.5"
django-crispy-forms = "==2.0"
django-allauth = "==0.52.0"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.11"
```

Comment: Missing comma after `'allauth.account'` causes implicit string concatenation.

Comment: i feel so dumb for such a silly thing it solved the issue thanks a lot man 
do you suggest any documentation for newbie like me

Comment: The official Python tutorial.